# React Hooks form showing undefined username in logs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-forms

I've integrated react hooks form in my react native app and I'm trying to connect the text input with the hooks controller for validation but when I write the username and click on the button it's showing username undefined not sure where the binding gone wrong please check and suggest what should I fix here?

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, useWindowDimensions, ScrollView, Alert, TextInput } from 'react-native'
import Logo  from '../../../assets/images/logo-main.png'
import CustomButton from '../../components/CustomButton/CustomButton';
import CustomInput from '../../components/CustomInput/CustomInput';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

import {useForm, Controller} from 'react-hook-form';

import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

const LoginScreen = () => {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const {height} = useWindowDimensions();
    const {control, handleSubmit} = useForm();
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const onLoginPressed = (data) => {
        console.log(data)
        // if (loading) {
        //     return;
        // }
        // setLoading(true);
        // try {
        //     response = await Auth.signIn(data.username, data.password);
        //     console.log(response);
        // } catch(e) {
        //     Alert.alert('Opps', e.message);
        // }
        // setLoading(false);
    };

    const onForgotPasswordPressed = () => {
        navigation.navigate('ForgotPassword');
    }

    const onRegisterPressed = () => {
        navigation.navigate('Register')
    }

  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <View style={styles.root}>
        <Image source={Logo} style={[styles.logo, {height : height * 0.2}]} resizeMode={'contain'} />

        {/* <CustomInput placeholder='Username' />
        <CustomInput placeholder='Password' secureTextEntry={true}/> */}

        <Controller control={control} name="username" render={({field: value, onChange, onBlur}) => 
        <TextInput value={value} onChangeText={onChange} onBlur={onBlur} placeholder='Username' /> } />

        <TextInput placeholder='Password'/>

        <CustomButton text={loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Login Account'} onPress={handleSubmit(onLoginPressed)} />
        <CustomButton text='Forgot Password?' onPress={onForgotPasswordPressed} type='TERTIARY' />
        <CustomButton text="Don't have an account? Create one" onPress={onRegisterPressed} type='TERTIARY' />
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    root: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 20,
    },

    logo: {
        width: 200,
        maxWidth: 300,
        maxHeight: 300,
    },
});

export default LoginScreen;
```

[image]

Comment: what is `handleSubmit`

Comment: @nullptr handleSubmit is a function provided by react hook form it validates the field before handling the onLoginPressed function in my case to check if the input fields are correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [`react-hook-form`](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/#Integratingwithglobalstate) approach, you should import the `controller` from `useForm`, and then in the `controller`, you can render a `TextInput`. Also, in the `controller's render` attribute, you can use `onChange,onBlur` and validate your inputs .

```
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
...


const LoginScreen = () => {
 ...

const { control, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
  defaultValues: {
    username: '',

  }
});
  ...


const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

return (
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
    ...


    <Controller
      control={control}
      rules={{
        required: true,
      }}
      render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          onChangeText={onChange}
          value={value}
          placeholder='Username'
        />
      )}
      name="username"
    />


    ...
  </ScrollView>

)
       }
```

Comment: @mr.niri bro I have stored the controller in the TextInput component and getting it to LoginScreen using props could and the error is (( TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.substring') )) could you please just give my code a look if possible:
LoginScreen:
https://pastebin.com/igchARRj

Input Component:
https://pastebin.com/CGTmmshx

Comment: @ImranIrshad Those links don't work for me.